# Start File Download via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, url, download

Currently, I am using an `a` with an `href`. But I don't want the client to be able to fetch the URL.

```
<a href="URL">Download</a>
```

Therefore, I simply want to ask **how it is possible to start a file download via Javascript**. (Presuming I have the URL available)

Comment: If you want the url protected you need to do that server side and generate one time download url's that have an identifier in them that you track. After it's used once (or can be time sensitive) the url no longer returns the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an  element without attaching it to any parent element so it is invisible to the user, and click it in JS.

```
link = document.createElement("a"); //create 'a' element
link.setAttribute("href", "file"); //replace "file" with link to file you want to download
link.setAttribute("download", "file");// replace "file" here too
link.click(); //virtually click <a> element to initiate download
```

The client will still be able to see the URL in the javascript code if they wanted, but the link is invisible.

Comment: Should note there are still browsers out there that don't support `download` on `<a>`